# How to make OpenVAS listen on an external interface?

Tags: kali-linux

I need to connect to my OpenVAS from the Internet to conduct penetration tests.

I didn't found any way to make it permanently listen on the external interface: `openvas-start` causes it to listen on 127.0.0.1.

I already tried to modify the configuration files, but it seems either I'm doing it wrong or something is overriding configurations when it starts.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I'm using Kali 2.0.

Comment: Not funny. Product-specific configuration questions are off-topic because they either belong on the vendors support page or the answers are in the manual. You also do not include any data on what configurations you tried or what errors or effects you were experiencing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since we're on **systemd**, you actually need to modify 3 `.service` files:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
```

Files are: greenbone-security-assistant.service, openvas-manager.service and openvas-scanner.service.

To make it quick you may want to use **sed**.
This line will replace all **127.0.0.1** to **0.0.0.0** which will allow all services be avaliable on all interfaces. You should replace **0.0.0.0** to the address of your choice.

```
sed -e 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' greenbone-security-assistant.service openvas-manager.service openvas-scanner.service
```

Verify, that all will be done as you want. If you're happy with the changes, just add `-i` to the end of previous command.

```
sed -e 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' greenbone-security-assistant.service openvas-manager.service openvas-scanner.service -i
```

Lastly you need to reload daemons, since you've made changes to files and restart services.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart greenbone-security-assistant.service openvas-manager.service openvas-scanner.service
```

Verify, that all services are listening on desired host:

```
ss -nalt
```

If restarting sevices didn't work, try to restart server itself.

Comment: This was the answer for me.  New version of Kali Linux since the openvas services have been added to systemd.

Answer (score 11):

1. openvas-stop
2. gsad --listen=0.0.0.0
3. openvas-start
4. From any client machine try https://kali-ip/
5. Enjoy accessing openvas web

Comment: This is much better than the accepted solution. Works on GVM 20.08

Comment: totally agree with you !

Answer (score 2):

There is much more simple solution. You can redirect external ip port to localhost using firewall. Assuming that Your's server external IP is **10.0.0.10**:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9392
```

That's all, now connect to https://10.0.0.10

I also tried to edit configuration IPs but there are in many places and seem to break OMP authorization. This solution was tested with latest Kali/OpenVAS (2016.09).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the openvasd man page:

> -a , --listen=
>                 Tell the server to only listen to  connections  on  the  address
>                   which  is  an  IP,  not a machine name. For instance,
>                 "openvasd -a 192.168.1.1" will  make  openvasd  only  listen  to
>                 requests  going  to 192.168.1.1 This option is useful if you are
>                 running openvasd on a gateway and if you don't  want  people  on
>                 the outside to connect to your openvasd.

You can append this option in the startup script located in `/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner` in the `DAEMONOPTS` constant.

Comment: added DAEMONOPTS="--listen=0.0.0.0" but netstat -na still shows Local Address
127.0.0.1:9390
127.0.0.1:9391
127.0.0.1:9392

Comment: Did you restart the daemon?

Comment: I ran openvas-stop then openvas-start respectively.

Comment: Also why didn't you specify the external address explicitly?

Comment: Run `/etc/init.d/openvas-scanner restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29437/discussion-between-sam-and-davidb).

Comment: I just tried this method but it doesn't seem to work. OpenVAS still seems to be binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of the public interface.

Comment: Are you talking about OpenVAS iself or the management interface?

Comment: I tried both.  FWIW I gave up and just downloaded the appliance which seems to be working.

Comment: is there a way how can I make this change permanent ? I mean if I run "gsad --listen=0.0.0.0" and then start openvas, I can reach it locally and externally. I couldnt find a config file where I can add this. /etc/default/greenbone-security-assistant or /etc/systemd/system/greenbone-security-assistant.service.d/local.conf didn't help me ..

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/default/greenbone-security-assistant`:

Change `127.0.0.1` to your IP

```
GSA_ADDRESS=your_server_IP_address
```

Then, restart the services:

```
root@tiger:/home/fw# ps aux | grep openvassd | grep -v grep
root      8918  2.6  1.2 138644 12212 ?        Ss   17:31   2:25 openvassd: Waiting for incoming connections
root@tiger:/home/fw#
root@tiger:/home/fw# killall openvassd
root@tiger:/home/fw#
root@tiger:/home/fw# ps aux | grep openvassd | grep -v grep
root@tiger:/home/fw#
root@tiger:/home/fw# service openvas-scanner start
root@tiger:/home/fw# service openvas-manager start
root@tiger:/home/fw# service greenbone-security-assistant restart
root@tiger:/home/fw#
root@tiger:/home/fw# ps aux | grep openvassd | grep -v grep
root      9681 39.4  1.3 123836 13476 ?        Ds   19:02   0:02 openvassd: Reloaded 7750 of 46062 NVTs (16% / ETA: 00:19)
root      9682  0.0  0.1 114564  1528 ?        S    19:02   0:00 openvassd (Loading Handler)
root@tiger:/home/fw#
```

Try to access it from outside `https://ip:9392`

Comment: I just tried this method but it doesn't seem to work.  OpenVAS still seems to be binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I used both Firewallengineer and Tim Rain's answers and that solved my issue. I did notice that for whatever reason in /lib/systemd/system I had to put --allow-header-host myserver.mycompany.com athe the end of the ExactStart line.

In /etc/default/greenbone-security-assistant I had to set the GSA_Address as the server address. This is what worked for me. I also had to access the server as myserver.mycompany.com:9392/omp, as just myserver.mycompany.com would not resolve. I understand my company's DNS needs a cleaning but I don;t have the time to fix that. Thank you both for your information, it saved me a lot of time and taught me quite a bit too.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my Kali and all applications (including GVM) I had a problem with the solution proposed in the first most voted one (which had worked before).

Now I needed to edit the:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/gsad.service
```

On the line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gsad --listen=x.x.x.x --port 9392
```

And then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo gvm-start
```